Sveltekit SSR not working even i didn't block it
I am using svelte 5 with typescript,
this is my vite conf,
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    },
    worker: {
        format: "es"
      },


});


this is my svelte conf,
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        files: {
            hooks: {
                client: 'src/lib/client/hooks.client',
                server: 'src/lib/server/hooks.server'
            },
            appTemplate: 'src/lib/client/app.html',
            errorTemplate: 'src/lib/client/error.html',
            serviceWorker: 'src/lib/client/service-worker'
        },
    }
};

export default config;

As you can see i did not block the ssr , or manualy on the pages with export const ssr = false,
but on my network tab, i checked the inital get request and my body shows up like this which is blocking the seo tools to understand my page content,
 <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents"><!--[--><!--[--><!----><!--[!--><!--]--><!----><!--]--> <!--[!--><!--]--><!--]-->

            <script>
                {
                    __sveltekit_dev = {
                        base: new URL(".", location).pathname.slice(0, -1),
                        env: {"PUBLIC_APP_ID":"0e4800----6b739","PUBLIC_FIREBASE_ALIAS":"m---tchi","PUBLIC_FIREBASE_ROOT_FOLDER":"--e-i","PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET":"me000----spot.com","PUBLIC_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN":"715749------K_c","PUBLIC_TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID":"-----"}
                    };

                    const element = document.currentScript.parentElement;

                    const data = [{"type":"data","data":{claims:void 0},"uses":{"dependencies":["app:user"]}},{"type":"data","data":null,"uses":{"dependencies":["app:room"]}}];

                    Promise.all([
                        import("/@fs/C:/AISocialMedia/aisocial/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/entry.js"),
                        import("/@fs/C:/AISocialMedia/aisocial/.svelte-kit/generated/client/app.js")
                    ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
                        kit.start(app, element, {
                            node_ids: [0, 3],
                            data,
                            form: null,
                            error: null
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body> 


So server side rendering not working for me , all my pages like this, i was thinking maybe using a client side sdk on the front page makes it . But issue is on all the pages.

I figured that out. If browser , if window checks blocks ssr. Don't use them if you use ssr.
